# Add Netsuite Sales order items

Tags: web-services, addition, netsuite

I am getting this type of error:

=> i am getting error in the integration of the netsuite.

In sales order add the items in the netsuite so there are some error is define in above section my code is below please see the code add how to solve this problem.

```
    [code] => USER_ERROR
    [message] => You must enter at least one line item for this transaction.
    [type] => ERRORi am gatting this type of error please help me
    [code] => USER_ERROR
    [message] => You must enter at least one line item for this transaction.
    [type] => ERROR
```

my code is

```
 include('NetSuiteService.php');

    $service = new NetSuiteService();
    if($order_items->netsuitid > 0){
        $internal_Id = $order_items->netsuitid;
        $emailCustomer = $order_items->user_email;
    }
    else{
        $customer_Info = $order->get_customer_info($order->user_id);
        $customer_information = array();
        foreach($customer_Info as $customer_key => $customer_value){
            if($customer_value->meta_key == 'first_name'){
                $customer_information['first_name'] = $customer_value->meta_value;
            }
            if($customer_value->meta_key == 'last_name'){
                $customer_information['last_name'] = $customer_value->meta_value;
            }
        }   

        $customer_information['email'] = $customer_Info->user_email;


        //Add customer into net suit integration
        $service = new NetSuiteService();

        $customer = new Customer();
        $customer->lastName = $customer_information['last_name'];
        $customer->firstName = $customer_information['first_name'];
        $customer->companyName = 'Company Name';
        $customer->phone = '2222222222';
        $customer->email = $customer_information['email'];
        $emailCustomer = $customer_information['email'];
        $request = new AddRequest();
        $request->record = $customer;

        $addResponse = $service->add($request);
        if (!$addResponse->writeResponse->status->isSuccess) {
            echo "You are already Registered with Netsuit.";
        } 
        else {
           $internal_Id = $addResponse->writeResponse->baseRef->internalId;
           $order->insert_Customer($internal_Id,$order->user_id);
        }
        //End customer into net suit integration
    }

    //Add Product Information
    /*$items = array();

    foreach ( $order_items as $item_id => $item ) {
        $itemRef = new nsRecordRef(array('internalId'=>$internal_Id));
        $qty = $item['qty'];
        if($item['type'] == 'line_item'){
            $salesOrderItemFieldArray = array(
                 "item" => $itemRef,
                 "quantity" => $qty

            );
        }
        if($item['type'] == 'fee'){
            $salesOrderItemFieldArray = array(
                 "item" => $itemRef,
                 "quantity" => $qty
            );
        }
        $SalesOrderItem->setFields($salesOrderItemFieldArray);
        $items[] = $SalesOrderItem;
    }

    $salesOrderItemList = new nsComplexObject("SalesOrderItemList");
    $salesOrderItemList->setFields(array(
         "item" => $items
    ));

    $salesOrderFields = array(
        "orderStatus" => $order->status,
        "entity" => '',
        "getAuth" => true,
        "shippingCost" => $order->order_shipping,
        "shipMethod" => $order->payment_method,
        "toBeEmailed" => true,
        "email" => $emailCustomer,
        "itemList" => $salesOrderItemList
    );*/

    $so = new SalesOrder();
    //created Date
    //$so->createdDate = $order->order_date;
    //entity
    $so->entity = new RecordRef();
    $so->entity->internalId = $internal_Id;
    $so->entity->name = $order->order_custom_fields['_billing_company'][0];

    //Transaction Id
    //$so->tranId = $order->order_custom_fields['Transaction ID'][0];

    //Transaction Paid Date
    //$so->tranDate = $order->order_custom_fields['_paid_date'][0];

    //Source
    $so->source = 'littlecrate';

    //Created From
    $so->createdFrom = 'littlecrate.com';

    //Currency Name
    require_once('geoplugin.class.php');
    $geoplugin = new geoPlugin();

    $geoplugin->currency = $order->order_custom_fields['_order_currency'];

    $so->currencyName = $geoplugin->countryName;
    $so->currency = $order->order_custom_fields['_order_currency'][0];

    //Discount
    $so->discountRate = $order->order_custom_fields['_order_discount'][0];

    //Tax
    $so->taxRate = $order->order_custom_fields['_order_tax'][0];

    //email
    $so->email  =  $order->billing_email;

    //Status
    //$so->orderStatus = $order->status;

    //Billing Address
    $so->billAddressList = array(
    'billFirstname' => $order->order_custom_fields['_billing_first_name'][0],
    'lastname' => $order->order_custom_fields['_billing_last_name'][0],
    'billAddressee' => $order->order_custom_fields['_billing_address_1'][0],
    'billAddr1' => $order->order_custom_fields['_billing_address_2'][0],
    'billCountry' => $order->order_custom_fields['_billing_country'][0],
    'billState' => $order->order_custom_fields['_billing_state'][0],
    'billZip' => $order->order_custom_fields['_billing_postcode'][0],
    'billPhone' => $order->order_custom_fields['_billing_phone'][0],
    'billEmail' => $order->order_custom_fields['_billing_email'][0]);

    //Shipping Address
    $so->shipAddressList = array(
    'shipFirstname' => $order->order_custom_fields['_shipping_first_name'][0],
    'shipLastname' => $order->order_custom_fields['_shipping_last_name'][0],
    'shipAddressee' => $order->order_custom_fields['_shipping_address_1'][0],
    'shipAddr1' => $order->order_custom_fields['_shipping_address_2'][0],
    'shipCity' => $order->order_custom_fields['_shipping_city'][0],
    'shipState' => $order->order_custom_fields['_shipping_state'][0],
    'shipZip' => $order->order_custom_fields['_shipping_postcode'][0],
    'shiplPhone' => $order->order_custom_fields['_billing_phone'][0],
    'shipEmail' => $order->order_custom_fields['_billing_email'][0]);

    //Ship Date
    //$so->shipDate = $order->order_custom_fields['Transaction ID'][0];

    //Shipping Method
    $so->shipMethod = $order->shipping_method;

    //Shipping Charges
    $so->shippingCost = $order->order_shipping;

    //Shipping Tax Rate
    $so->shippingTax1Rate = $order->order_shipping_tax;

    //Payment Method
    $so->paymentMethod = $order->payment_method;

    //Sub Total
    //$so->subTotal = $order->order_total;

    //Discount Total(Cart Total)
    //$so->discountTotal = $order->cart_discount;

    //Tax Total
    //$so->taxTotal = $order->order_tax;

    //Total
    //$so->total = $order->order_total;

    //Product Listing
    $arrItemsList = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($order_items_product as $keyProduct =>$valueProduct){
        if($valueProduct['type'] == 'line_item'){
        //$arrItemsList[$i]['item']['internalId']   = $valueProduct['product_id'];
        //$arrItemsList[$i]['item']['externalId']   = $keyProduct;
        $arrItemsList[$i]['item']['name']           = $valueProduct['name'];
        $arrItemsList[$i]['item']['quantity']       = $valueProduct['qty'];
        $arrItemsList[$i]['item']['description']    = $valueProduct['type'];
        $arrItemsList[$i]['item']['amount']         = $valueProduct['line_total'];
        }
        if($valueProduct['type'] == 'fee'){
        //$arrItemsList[$i]['item']['internalId']   = $valueProduct['product_id'];
        //$arrItemsList[$i]['item']['externalId']   = $keyProduct;
        $arrItemsList[$i]['item']['name']           = $valueProduct['name'];
        $arrItemsList[$i]['item']['quantity']       = $valueProduct['qty'];
        $arrItemsList[$i]['item']['description']    = $valueProduct['type'];
        $arrItemsList[$i]['item']['amount']         = $valueProduct['line_total'];
        }
        $i++;
    }

    //print_r($arrItemsList);

    $so->itemList->item = $arrItemsList;

    /*$so->itemList = new SalesOrderItemList();
    $soi = new SalesOrderItem();
    $soi->item = new RecordRef();
    $soi->item->internalId = 15;
    $soi->quantity = 3;
    $soi->price = new RecordRef();
    $soi->price->internalId = $id;
    $soi->amount = 55.3;
    $so->itemList->item = array($soi);*/

    $request = new AddRequest();
    $request->record = $so;
    //print_r($request);

    $addResponse = $service->add($request);
    print_r($addResponse);
    exit;
    if (!$addResponse->writeResponse->status->isSuccess) {
        echo "ADD ERROR";
    } else {
        echo "ADD SUCCESS, id " . $addResponse->writeResponse->baseRef->internalId;
    }
    +
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Completed Using The Help Of Saqib:

http://stackoverflow.com/users/810555/saqib

He is a Great Developer And Regarding Netsuite Information Please Contact To Saqib Thanks Man U Just Do It.

```
<?php
    $order_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                
        // create array of fields
        $itemArr = array();
        $i = 0;
        foreach($order_items_product as $keyProduct =>$valueProduct){
            //if you not have internal id of item in netsuuite then please add the item in the netsuite and try.
            $netsuiteItemId = 'Your Item Internal id Which is in the Netsuite Item';
            
            $itemArr[$i]['item']['internalId'] = $netsuiteItemId;
            $itemArr[$i]['quantity'] = $valueProduct['qty'];
            $i++;
        }
        
        if (!define('LF', "\n")) {
            define('LF', "\n");
        }
        
         /* for use in formatting custom addresses since NetSuite converts to <br> */
        //Billing Address Information
        /* this example has the customer address info in a db record, just pulled into $row */
        $billAddress = stripslashes($order->order_custom_fields['_billing_first_name'][0]) . ' ' . $order->order_custom_fields['_billing_last_name'][0] . LF;
        $billAddress .= stripslashes($order->order_custom_fields['_billing_address_1'][0]).LF;
        $billAddress .= stripslashes($order->order_custom_fields['_billing_address_2'][0]).LF;
        $billAddress .= stripslashes($order->order_custom_fields['_billing_country'][0]).LF;
        $billAddress .= stripslashes($order->order_custom_fields['_billing_state'][0]) . ' - ' . $order->order_custom_fields['_billing_postcode'][0] . ', ' . LF;
        $billAddress .= $order->order_custom_fields['_billing_phone'][0] . ', ' . $order->order_custom_fields['_billing_email'][0];
        
        //Shipping Address Information
        $shipAddress = stripslashes($order->order_custom_fields['_shipping_first_name'][0]) . ' ' . $order->order_custom_fields['_shipping_last_name'][0] . LF;
        $shipAddress .= stripslashes($order->order_custom_fields['_shipping_address_1'][0]).LF;
        $shipAddress .= stripslashes($order->order_custom_fields['_shipping_address_2'][0]).LF;
        $shipAddress .= stripslashes($order->order_custom_fields['_shipping_city'][0]).LF;
        $shipAddress .= stripslashes($order->order_custom_fields['_shipping_state'][0]) . ', ' . $order->order_custom_fields['_shipping_postcode'][0] . ', ' . LF;
        $shipAddress .= $order->order_custom_fields['_billing_phone'][0] .', '. $order->order_custom_fields['_billing_email'][0];
        
        
        $purchaseOrderFields = array (
                            'entity' => array ('internalId' => $internal_Id, 'type' => 'customer'),
                            'shippingCost' => $order->order_shipping,
                            'shipMethod' => $order->payment_method,
                            'toBeEmailed' => true,
                            //'tranId' => $order->order_custom_fields['Transaction ID'][0],
                            //'tranDate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                            'source' => 'littlecrate',
                            'createdFrom' => 'littlecrate.com',
                            'discountRate' => $order->order_custom_fields['_order_discount'][0],
                            'taxRate' => $order->order_custom_fields['_order_tax'][0],
                            'email' => $order->billing_email,
                            //'shipDate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                            'shipMethod' => $order->shipping_method,
                            'shippingCost' => $order->order_shipping,
                            'shippingTax1Rate' => $order->order_shipping_tax,
                            'paymentMethod' => $order->payment_method,
                            //'taxTotal' => $order->order_tax,
                            //'total' => $order->order_total,
                            'billAddress' => $billAddress,
                            'shipAddress' => $shipAddress,
                            'itemList' => array (
                                                    'item' => $itemArr
                                                )
                                    );
    
        $salesOrder = new nsComplexObject('SalesOrder');
        
        $salesOrder ->setFields($purchaseOrderFields);
    
        $addResponse = $myNSclient->add($salesOrder );
        if (!$addResponse->isSuccess) {
            echo "Order Information is Not Inserted Into The Netsuite. Please Contact to Administration."; 
            exit;
        } 
    
        ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You item List object doesn't seem in correct format. Your code should look like this

```
$itemArr = array();
foreach($order_items_product as $keyProduct =>$valueProduct){
    $item = new SalesOrderItem();
    $item->item = $valueProduct['product_id'];
    $item->quantity = $valueProduct['qty'];
    $itemArr[] = $item;
}

$itemList = new SalesOrderItemList();
$itemList->item = $itemArr;

$so->itemList->item = $itemList;
```

Comment: Hello Saqib,Thanks for Reply, Can u send me the hole code of How To Add sales product in the net Suite

Comment: Means How To Add Sales Order

Comment: Rest of your code seems fine. Just plug-in my snippet and it should work.

Comment: Hello Thanks Again For Your Valuable Reply. I trying to solve this issue but still facing some problem like this.  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soapenv:Server.userException] org.xml.sax.SAXException: item on {urn:sales_2013_1.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com}SalesOrderItemList must be of type {urn:sales_2013_1.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com}SalesOrderItem in /var/www/littlecrate/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/classes/shortcodes/NSPHPClient.php:297 .... Please Help Me To Solve This Problem. Thanks in Advance.